# PHP mail: What does -f do?

Tags: php

While troubleshooting a contact form with an e-mail host they told me to use '-f' in the from address of the php mail function. What does the "-f" flag do and why would that be a fix for allowing an e-mail to be delivered? I read some of the documentation but I'm not quite clear on it.

Example code:

```
mail($emailAddress, $mailSubject, $mailBody, $headers, '-f ' . $mailFrom);
```

PS: without the "-f" it works just fine for the big e-mail hosts (hotmail, gmail, etc, but for whatever reason not for the smaller host I'm working with)

Thanks

Comment: Your example is missing the additional_headers parameter.

Comment: Since there's already a place to specify a "from" address within the mail() function, it is strange to have an additional -f option

Comment: as @nickb says, this is the correct order of parameters: `($email_to, "$email_subject", $email_body, $email_headers, '-f ' . $email_from)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`-f` is a parameter to the mailer (usually sendmail). From [the docs](http://php.net/mail):

> The additional_parameters parameter can be used to pass additional
>   flags as command line options to the program configured to be used
>   when sending mail, as defined by the sendmail_path configuration
>   setting. **For example, this can be used to set the envelope sender
>   address when using sendmail with the -f sendmail option.**

Here is the [man page for sendmail](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/man/sendmail.html), you can see what the `-f` option does:

```
-fname           Sets the name of the ``from'' person (i.e., the sender of the
                 mail).  -f can only be used by ``trusted'' users (normally
                 root, daemon, and network) or if the person you are trying to
                 become is the same as the person you are.
```

Comment: Just a followup @nickb, the `-f` in the example is the 4th parameter and the PHP docs mention that this should be in the 5th - am I reading things wrong here?

Comment: @hafichuk - The example is missing the email headers - It is the 5th parameter to `mail()`.

Comment: So is it just marking the from e-mail address as being sent from a trusted user on the web hosting server then? Along with that, I didn't write this code, just maintaining it, but is it good practice to have the from address be the e-mail address the user entered in to the form?

Comment: Its setting the email envelope's email address (the sender), which must be what your smaller host is reading to determine who sent the mail (instead of the From: header, or both, perhaps).

Comment: @ToddBFisher - You should be careful when you allow users to specify an address as the email's sender... They can spoof legitimate email addresses to the unsuspecting user (even though the raw email / headers will show that the email is illegitimate).

Comment: That's kinda what I thought, just wanted a second opinion. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I read both docs linked to above, and I still do not understand `-f`. If I have a contact form, so users can send me an email, would I set `-f` to be the visitor's email, my (3rd party) actual email address (different from the website's domain name), or a generic email address using the domain name (iserver has email, but I don't use it for this site.)

Answer (score 5):

The -f option is to set the bounce mail address. Sending a message without one can negatively influence the spam-score that is being calculated over the message. Messages with low scores sometimes get filtered out for certain hosts.

You can use https://www.mail-tester.com/ to test the score of your message. You can expirement with or without the -f flag and see the score change.

Answer (score 3):

It is a flag to mark the following text ($mailFrom) to be used as "from" address of the mail.

Have a look at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php