# Add a flag to send an email - cakephp

Tags: php, email, cakephp

To send an email to my provider, I should insert the -f flag before the e-mail address. That is, if I use this:

```
App::uses( 'CakeEmail', 'Network/Email' );
$email = new CakeEmail( );
$email->from( 'from@ext_domain.com' );
$email->to( 'to@my_domain.com' );
$email->subject( 'Subject' );
$email->emailFormat( 'text' );
$email->send( 'My message' );
```

I do not receive anything. 
I should add: "-f to@my_domain.com" 
Where should I add this flag?

Comment: What's the `-f` flag for? What does it do? Where is it meant to be set on? the email client?

Comment: I do not know. This flag is required by the provider.

Comment: @LatheesanKanes It's most probably a sendmail flag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306576/php-mail-what-does-f-do

Comment: How to use this flag in cakephp?

Comment: btw, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: Sorry. The version is 2.4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your server doesn't run in safe mode, you can define flags in the somewhat undocumented `additionalParameters` email config option, which is exclusive to [**`MailTransport`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.6/lib/Cake/Network/Email/MailTransport.php).

```
class EmailConfig {

    public $yourConfig = array(
        'transport' => 'Mail',
        'from' => 'from@example.com',
        // ...
        'additionalParameters' => '-ffrom@example.com'
    );

    // ...
}
```

Note that the `-f` flag is ment for defining the *sender*, not the *recipient*, so it should most likely be set to `from@...`, not `to@...`.

Comment: Excuse me for my superficiality. 
The cakePHP version is 2.4.6. 
This is the problem: my domain is www.dominio.com. 
The contact page, on the same domain, send an email to info@dominio.com. Under these conditions, the email never arrives. 
I have to put the -f flag before the address. 
The method you suggested causes this message: "An Internal Error Has Occurred." 

Can you help me? thanks

Comment: @Sandro You'll have to check your logs (`app/tmp/logs/`), they should contain the exact error message. If not, make sure that [**debug mode**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#cakephp-core-configuration) is enabled, [**logging**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html) is configured properly, and then try again.

Comment: @Sandro Sorry, had a look at the wrong source, the exact error message isn't logged in 2.4.6 yet. Try the 2.5 beta, or temporarily remove the `@` char from the `mail()` command in `MailTransport::_mail()`.

Comment: I do not know what happens. If I insert the -f flag, the mail arrives, but I get the "Error 500". The log file tells me this: 2014-04-03 09:35:46 Error: [SocketException] Could not send email.
Request URL: /xxx/Customers/contact
Stack Trace:
#0 lib/Cake/Network/Email/MailTransport.php(51): MailTransport->_mail('info@xxx...', 'Richiesta di: S...', 'xxx...', 'From: xxx@xx...', '-f info@xxx...')
#1 /lib/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php(1122): MailTransport->send(Object(CakeEmail))
#2 /app/Controller/CustomersController.php(48): CakeEmail->send('xxx')

Comment: @Sandro Have you done what I've suggested? Tested against 2.5.0, or temporarily removed the `@` from the `mail()` call in order to be able to see the exact error message (in case any is triggered)? You could also create a simple script that invokes `mail()` with the given parameters to see if any error pops up and figure it out from there. There's nothing more I can tell you at this point, you have to do some debugging on your own.