# How to send -f parameter equivalent from swiftmail?

Tags: php, sendgrid, swiftmailer

I am trying to migrate from PHP mail to SendGrid using swift mail. I am not able to understand `-f email` additional parameter.

```
mail($Email,$sub,$cont,$headers,'-f noreply@mydomain.com')
```

I am not sure what type of header is this. Should i send this as path_header?

I could not undersrtand the explanation of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306576/php-mail-what-does-f-do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is used to set the "envelope from" on your email; it's not actually a header. [This post](https://www.protectedtrust.com/knowledgebase/envelope-address-vs-message-header-address/) describes what that means.

When sending via SendGrid you won't need to specify this flag or explicitly set your "envelope from." Just set your from address and fromName and you'll be good to go.